# Extending a class with common functionality

Tags: php, oop, abstract-class, extending

I have three classes which basically do very similar things;

1. Store a record of an uploaded file.
2. Move and upload the file.
3. Set the status of the record to active or revoked.

One of the classes has an additional update method. Each class references a different table in the database because although some of the fields are common, there are a couple of fields extra in some of the tables.

As quite a lot of the functionality is common I think it may be best to extend a base class rather than duplicating a lot of the functionality.

My only quarrel is the construct function on the base class. As some of the fields in each table are additional I'm concerned this will prevent a base class.

I have thought of using an abstract class as this will allow me to extend on functionality whilst maintaining most of the things in one place. But it's the problem with the construct. Can I have an abstract class with no construct?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you: You can have *any* class without `__construct()`. And you can always overwrite every method (except methods, that are declared as `final`) of a parent class in a child class.

Comment: Is it good practice to have an abstract class without a constrictor and having child classes with?

Comment: It is good practice to implement constructors in classes, which requires a constructor ;) You can not say "Constructor in concrete classes, but not in abstract ones", or vice versa. A constructor should bring a class in a useful and valid initial state, what includes, that they maybe need initial values or references to other objects. If you see, that your class needs something to set up, before it is useable, its a good job for a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry but I guess I do not completely understand your question. Anyway in inherited class you can always override the constructor  and within it invoke the superclass constructor plus further stuff if needed.